# Whats more efficient, returning all columns or casting to model in linq C#

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a database table with 20 columns but I only need to work with 8 of the columns.

Is it more efficient to return the whole table

```
_context.products.where(x => x.active);
```

Or is it better to do this

```
_context.products.where(x => x.active).select(x => new SubModels.ProductItem { id = x.id, name = x.name, category = x.category etc etc});
```

Thanks

Comment: It is always more efficient to return only the data you need.

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought I remembered reading a while back, just wanted to confirm it. Thanks!

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was much in it though

Comment: The function as a whole is pretty demanding so I need to make every thing as efficient as possible.

Comment: If `_context.products` is a collection of model objects that are already there, it would be faster to select existing objects than create new ones (though probably not faster enough to matter). But if you're getting data from a server via Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL, then you're creating new objects anyway, and you want to minimize bandwidth. It's the latter case, right? I think you're missing a tag. "LINQ" doesn't mean "query the server".

Comment: I think the latter way seems to be the best way for my needs as Im working with two contexts and if I dont cast as the model the code complains about using two different contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pretty much refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful) "Why is SELECT * considered harmful".

It seems rather relevant to your case and has a lot of points.

So it's always better from performance point of view of one query to select only what you need. But you should always consider some other things like likelihood of issuing additional queries to get the data you could have returned already.

Answer (score 0):

The select is more efficient, because it queries just the data you need. on your first example, it will query all columns on the db.

Comment: i feel like there is not enough information provided to determine that there will be a full table scan

Comment: It will not perform a [table scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_table_scan), that's something else entirely. That would be related to the `Where` clause not the `select`.

Comment: It's not because you query all columns that you do a table scan. Note that OP is not querying all rows.

Comment: ahh true, I didnt pay attention to the Where clause. rushed my answer